# how to display the value of an input element based on the value from other input element in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have and array of an object 'say' person { name: string, age: number }. In my html, I am displaying name as input element with  selection. If I select a name from this selection, i would like to display person's corresponding age in the age input element.  Anyone knows how to do this? Here is my html code:

```
<!-- Display person's name -->
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Person Name</span>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.name" name="personName"  list="persons" required>
        <datalist id="persons">
            <option *ngFor='let p of person_list' value={‌{p.name}} selected>
                {‌{p.name}}
            </option>
        </datalist>
 </div>
<!-- Display age -->
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Age</span>
        <input type ="text"
                placeholder="Age"  
                [(ngModel)]="selectdPerson.age"
                name="age" required>
</div>
```

How do I display Age based on my selection of person's name?  Both of these input elements are on the same page/component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the selected person age value when the selected person changes via the `ngModelChange` output event.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Person Name</span>

  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.name" name="personName"  list="persons" required (ngModelChange)="onChanged($event)">

  <datalist id="persons">
    <option *ngFor="let p of person_list" [value]="p.name" selected>
        {{p.name}}
    </option>
  </datalist>

</div>
<!-- Display age -->
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Age</span>
  <input type ="text"
          placeholder="Age"  
          [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.age"
          name="age" required>
</div>
```

And in your component definition:

```
    export class MyComponent {

      person_list: any[] = [
                    {name: 'aaa', age: 21},  
                    {name: 'bbb', age: 31},  
                    {name: 'ccc', age: 41}];

      selectedPerson: any =  {};

      onChanged($event){
        var match = this.person_list.find(x => x.name === $event);
        this.selectedPerson.age = match.age;
      }

    }
```

I haven't tried binding with `datalist` before so not sure if this is supported out-of-the-box like e.g. `select` element. There may be a simpler way to do this (perhaps another answer will help)

Comment: It works, but only when I select the person name from list very first time. If I try to re-select, it gives an error that unable to get the property age. I think it is coming from onChanged() method. As I type backspace to clear my person's name selection, it triggers onChanged() immediately. This causes match = null. To fix it, I put this.selectedPerson.age = match.age under if (match != null) {}. Now it is working.  Thanks for your answer garth74.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that null check.
No problems :-)